# Set PC to auto shutdown after a certain period of idle time unless programs are downloading

Tags: windows-10, script, shutdown, utorrent, task-scheduler

I was trying to create a scheduled task in Windows 10 in order to shutdown the PC automatically after 90 minutes of idle. The problem is that the system shuts down itself even if utorrent is running and downloading. Is there a way to add an exception to the task via a script (shutdown unless utorrent process is launched and running or unless there is network activity)?

Comment: If you can script the check for whether downloads are in progress, Windows provides the `shutdown.exe` utility which you can use to actually shut down the system. Please note that we are not a script-writing service.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thank you and sorry for the improper request!

Comment: No worries yet! You might just need to split this question into two: first figure out how to determine if utorrent is downloading anything, then figure out how to write a script that shuts down the system if it's not. At least the latter should be trivial, and if the former is possible, how to do it is very likely to be documented somewhere. Show us that you have tried by yourself first, and we can help fill in the missing pieces.

Comment: In relation to what Michael said is there an option to close utorrent after it completes all downloads? If so you could check to see if the application is open instead. It will make it easier.